# $.post to a django view does not pass the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post, django-templates

I am using $.post in jquery to send a request to a different page.

```
<body>
<form id="saveuserFeedback" class="form" action="{% url saveFeedback  %}" method="post"        class="ajax"> {% csrf_token %}
...
...
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="Like" value="Like"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="Discuss" value="Dislike"/> 
...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Like").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Like clicked');
        console.log('reached here');
        $.post("saveFeedback2/", {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            feedbackStatus: "Like",
            feedbackNoteID: "12345"
        });
    });
    $("#Dislike").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Dislike clicked');
        console.log('reached here');
        $.post("saveFeedback2/", {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            feedbackStatus: "Dislike",
            feedbackNoteID: "12345"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

However, in saveFeedback2, the data seems to be not available.I can only see the csrfmiddlewaretoken passed.

```
 def saveFeedback2(request):
        print request.POST
```

> QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'18f0f434b876a3b742371c6b43222b4a']}>

The following is in urls.py

```
url(r'saveFeedback2/$', saveFeedback2 , name='saveFeedback2'),
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Remove `type="submit"` from the input buttons and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is, you are not doing a `preventDefault` for the form's submit. You are doing it for the `click` event (Which i dont think is required. But anyways..).

Add this in your `$(document).ready()`

```
$('#saveuserFeedback').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

A cleaner approach could be to have `like` and `dislike` as radio buttons, and then on form submit, do a `data = $('form').serialize()` and then send that into the `$.post`